# Trying to start kubernetes service/deployment

Tags: service, deployment, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to get a service running in minikube (MetaMap Tagger service, medpost-skr).

I have the following Docker file that runs fine on its own:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

RUN mkdir /usr/share/public_mm
ADD public_mm/MedPost-SKR /usr/share/public_mm/MedPost-SKR
ADD public_mm/bin /usr/share/public_mm/bin
ADD required/scripts /usr/share/public_mm/scripts

ENV PATH=/usr/share/public_mm/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR  /usr/share/public_mm

# --- BUILD ---
RUN  /usr/share/public_mm/bin/install.sh

# --- START ---
CMD skrmedpostctl start
```

And I have the following service/deployment file (in argo workflow template) to start up the service:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow                  #new type of k8s spec
metadata:
  generateName: nlp-adapt-wf-    #name of workflow spec
spec:
  entrypoint: nlp-adapt-metamap-services          #invoke the build template

  templates:

  - name: nlp-adapt-metamap-services
    steps:
    - - name: medpost-deployment
        template: medpost-server-d
    - - name: medpost-service
        template: medpost-server-s

  - name: medpost-server-d
    resource:
      action: create
      manifest: |
        apiVersion: apps/v1
        kind: Deployment
        metadata:
          name: medpost
        spec:
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              app: medpost
              track: stable
          template:
            metadata:
              labels:
                app: medpost
                track: stable

            spec:
              containers:
              - image: ahc-nlpie-docker.artifactory.umn.edu/medpost-skr
                imagePullPolicy: Never
                name: medpost
                ports:
                - containerPort: 1795

  - name: medpost-server-s
    resource:
      action: create
      manifest: |
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Service
        metadata:
          name: medpost
          namespace: default
          labels:
            app: medpost

        spec:
          selector:
            app: medpost
          ports:
          - name: test1 
            protocol: TCP
            port: 1795
            targetPort: 1795
```

When I look at the services, I see:

(base) D20181472:medpost-skr gms$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1                443/TCP    60d
medpost      ClusterIP   10.100.189.245           1795/TCP   26m

and when I look at the deployment, it looks like the service deployment never got started:

```
(base) D20181472:medpost-skr gms$ kubectl get deploy
NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
medpost   0/1     1            0           27m
```

However, when I look at the logs for the pod, it appears the service started, but the pod is in a CrashLoopBackOff condition:

```
(base) D20181472:medpost-skr gms$ kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
medpost-859844ddf-sw888         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   10         28m

(base) D20181472:medpost-skr gms$ kubectl logs medpost-859844ddf-sw888
$Starting skrmedpostctl:
started.
```

Here is more info about the pod:

```
kubectl describe pod medpost-859844ddf-sw888
Name:               medpost-859844ddf-sw888
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:         Tue, 02 Apr 2019 14:14:57 -0500
Labels:             app=medpost
                    pod-template-hash=859844ddf
                    track=stable
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 172.17.0.7
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/medpost-859844ddf
Containers:
  medpost:
    Container ID:   docker://208de2cc7c5007b53b63f2a063db13a8df5011488ab0be26726c12de54735043
    Image:          ahc-nlpie-docker.artifactory.umn.edu/medpost-skr
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:89ea83d80cd906319afbdd37805228440048aded93156c0fc17f900d1aa6228b
    Port:           1795/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 02 Apr 2019 14:41:17 -0500
      Finished:     Tue, 02 Apr 2019 14:41:17 -0500
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  10
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-mkpqk (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-mkpqk:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-mkpqk
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  30m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/medpost-859844ddf-sw888 to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     28m (x5 over 30m)     kubelet, minikube  Container image "ahc-nlpie-docker.artifactory.umn.edu/medpost-skr" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    28m (x5 over 30m)     kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Normal   Started    28m (x5 over 30m)     kubelet, minikube  Started container
  Warning  BackOff    5m6s (x117 over 30m)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
```

**Edit**
here is the deployment:

```
(base) D20181472:wsd_server gms$ kubectl describe deploy medpost
Name:                   medpost
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Tue, 02 Apr 2019 18:03:13 -0500
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=medpost,track=stable
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=medpost
           track=stable
  Containers:
   medpost:
    Image:        ahc-nlpie-docker.artifactory.umn.edu/medpost-skr
    Port:         1795/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  Progressing    True    ReplicaSetUpdated
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   medpost-859844ddf (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  34s   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set medpost-859844ddf to 1
```

Not sure what to make out of this?

Comment: Do you have any logs for your pod application? It sounds like something is wrong with the application, it crashes and so your deployment restarts the pod, but it keeps crashing.

Comment: I posted the output above. It is where it started the service in question: `$Starting skrmedpostctl: started.`, which is the desired response.

Comment: It still sounds like something in the application is broken that is just not getting put out to the logs. There could be reasons I don't know about, that's just the only time I have run into that CrashLoopBackoff. Could your application logging be getting consumed and not making it out?

Comment: Understood. That's why I closed my question with "Not sure what to make out of this?" Unfortunately, this and another service are dependencies for yet another service I have to get up and running... this looks like a rabbit hole of weird issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that these services were being started as background processes. Starting them in the foreground was the solution.